How to save plots using ggMarginal?
ggsave() does not work as it treats the margins as transparent as shown in the following screenshot:

I tried doing png() and dev.off() but didn't have success. Is ggsave() not natively supported with the ggExtra package?
Question is straightforward. This text is me filling in whitespace to fulfill the character requirement.

I tried the example from their manual, png works fine: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggExtra/vignettes/ggExtra.html What is the issue?

Also, once we use ggextra the object is not a ggplot class, it is "ggExtraPlot" "gtable"      "gTree"       "grob"        "gDesc"

Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78196022/12957340

Set the background colour for the backaground in ggsave explicitly:
library(ggExtra)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x =runif(100),
  y =rnorm(100)
)


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  theme_minimal()

print(p)

p2 <- ggMarginal(p, 
                 type = "histogram", 
                 colour = "black", 
                 fill = "blue")

print(p2)

ggsave("test.png", 
       p2, 
       width = 8, height = 6, 
       units = "in",
       bg = "white")

